# Best option for making a mint pc unbootable by anyone but me?

Tags: linux-mint, boot, grub2

I've just installed Mint 18.03 on my new PC and plan to use it as the sole OS on this system. Now and again I go to public LAN parties and leave my PC unattended along with many others overnight. I'd like to create an additional layer of security to  ensure that nobody else can reasonably access my PC beyond having a user/pw login.

During the install I put /boot on a USB thumbdrive, with the intention that when I leave my PC after shutting it down I can remove this drive and take it with me, meaning the PC cannot be booted up without this or a similar drive (which would seem unrealistic at a LAN party).

I'm having issues however creating a backup for this USB, I've looked at a lot of threads using `dd` to bytewise copy the /boot USB onto another drive, as well as [straight up just installing grub2 onto the backup drive](https://www.pendrivelinux.com/install-grub2-on-usb-from-ubuntu-linux/).

There isn't too much material on this topic and it's made me wonder if there is perhaps a better way to go about something like this? Ideally I'd like it if nobody but me could even boot or reach the login screen via the use of something like a USB.

Comment: LUKS with a prompted password at boot. (Or a USB key.) Veracrypt likewise.

Comment: Just install all of mint (maybe excluding `/home`) on the USB drive.

Comment: What are the issues with `dd` you are having?

Comment: @ajeh dd completes fine after copying the entire boot drive to another USB, however I get the blinking cursor when I try and boot to it, indicating that my machine can't find a bootable disk

Comment: What exactly is your command? You may be targeting a wrong device, or not `sync`ing `dd` output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing to do is to use full disk encryption (LUKS) on the whole disk.

In addition, you should set a BIOS password.

I wouldn't bother putting `/boot` into a USB drive that you take away since someone could open your computer, take out the drive, and connect the drive to another machine to snoop its contents. Once someone has physical access to your hardware, they have pretty much access to anything that's not encrypted.

Comment: As you and @roaima say I think this is actually the best solution for my situation. I didn't realise that /boot contained things I wouldn't want people to necessarily see. Looks like I can achieve what I'm looking for by having /boot on an unencrypted part of of my disk and using USB unlock. Will also do the hardening work later on as you suggested.